# union two tables and order by a common field like name which is present in both the tables

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have two tables a and b which has a field name in it.

I need to list the data from these two tables. I thought of using union but in the result list data from the first table appears and then followed by the second.

what i want is to order by the field name so the result should be a mixed up of two tables in the order of name that is order by name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select slug, name, 1 as mt 
  from tablea 
union 
select slug, name, 0 as mt 
  from tableb 
 order 
    by name;
```

The above is working well for me. will there be any complications in the result of this?

Comment: Union eliminates duplicate rows. You won't have duplicate rows from tablea, tableb because of your "mt" column, but if you have dups in either table they will be eliminated. Use "union all" if you need to keep dups.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your query is

```
SELECT field1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE 1 
UNION SELECT field1 FROM TABLE2 WHERE 1
```

u can make it a subquery like this

```
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT field1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE 1 
UNION SELECT field1 FROM TABLE2 WHERE 1) AS `result` ORDER BY `result`.`field1`
```

Comment: `WHERE 1` -- is that really valid syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could use a Join query such as:

```
SELECT tablea.firstname, tablea.middlename, tablea.lastname, tableb.phone 
FROM tablea, tableb 
WHERE tablea.ID = tableb.ID
```

Then, you could sort the result however you like.